# Send requests from google assistant to my server

Tags: webhooks, google-assistant

I would like to trigger my private webserver's endpoint via google assistant.
I have several endpoints in that server, some of them control my home devices, some of them are just automation of everyday tasks.
Looking into the [docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/docs) I saw that conversational API will be removed in 2 months and that this is the best match for my needs.
Some of my automations are controlled via IFTTT but the phrases are forced ("activate #SCENE#") and do not allow more complex phrases and responses ("add cheese to the shopping list" -> "which cheese would you like to add?", for example).
I would like to know if there is an alternative to conversational API or at least a way to trigger an endpoint with some parameters ("add #ITEM# to shopping list" without the response).